# How to get a natural log integral answer in exact answer?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$\int^{-1}_{-2}\frac{4x^5-2x^2}{x^3}\,dx$ is the problem I'm working with.
I did a step by step solution and the last step before the answer was $\frac{4x^3}{3}-2\ln|x|$, and I'm trying to figure out how did that turn into $\frac{28}{3}+2\ln (2)$. I can see how $28\over3$ happened and I know ln is a part of the equation, but how was the absolute value of $2$ determined to be the exact answer? I tried $-1-(-2)$ but that gives $-3$, so why is it $\ln(2)$?

Comment: It's because $\ln(1)=0$. Note also that $\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$, not $\ln(a+b)$.

Comment: For the record, $-1 - (-2) \neq -3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left. \left(\frac{4x^3}{3} -2\ln|x|\right) \ \right|_{-2}^{-1}$$
$$=\left(-\frac{4}{3}-2\ln|-1|\right) - \left(-\frac{32}{3}-2\ln |-2| \right)$$
$$=\frac{28}{3} + 2(\ln 2 - \ln 1)$$
$$=\frac{28}{3} + 2\ln 2$$